# Interrupt a accept winsock call with Asynchronous Procedure calls in MFC

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, winsock

The problem is simple,

I have a daemon thread which waits for incoming client connections and when atleast one client connects, it exits.

Now, when someone calls shutdownApp function, I need to send the signal(or interrupt) to the daemon thread and ask it to come out of blocking accept so that it can exit.

I don't want to use

1) Selects (or non blocking threads) 
2) TerminateThread

MFC mentions that a winsock's accept function can be interrupted via Asynchronous Procedure Calls. If anyone has pointers on how to do it, it would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply close the socket that `accept()` is being called on. That will cause `accept()` to fail with an error code that the thread can then check for.  If you read the documentation more carefully, it mentions that an APC can abort `accept()` prematurely to warn you against calling `accept()` again while the APC is still running. That does not mean you should intentionally use an APC to abort `accept()`, that is the wrong solution.

If you do not want to close the socket, then use `select()` in a loop.  It works on both blocking and non-blocking sockets, and will tell you when to call `accept()` so it does not block.  Specify a timeout so that your thread can wake up periodically to look for a termination condition before calling `select()` again.